# custom absolute function is not working for large long values in Scala

Tags: scala

I have written custom function to get absolute value for long number. Below is the

```
def absolute(x:Long):Long= x match {
 case y:Long if(y<0) => -1 * y
 case y if(y>=0) => y
}

println(absolute(-9223372036854775808L))
println(absolute(-2300L))
```

Below is the output of above program

```
-9223372036854775808
2300
```

I am not sure why it is working for very big long values. Ang suggestions on the same.

Comment: If either of the posts below answered your question please accept one.

Answer (score 6):

This is just a case of integer overflow:

```
scala> Long.MaxValue
res0: Long = 9223372036854775807

scala> Long.MinValue
res1: Long = -9223372036854775808
```

Thus when you negate `-9223372036854775808` you are overflowing the `Long` by 1 unit, causing it to wrap around (to itself!).

Also there is no need for a match here:

```
scala> def abs(x: Long): Long = if (x < 0) -x else x
abs: (x: Long)Long
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use scala.math.abs?
See [scala.math](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.0/scala/math/package.html)